# Visual Studio 2008 crashes when I try to open Resource View. How do i fix it?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, porting, visual-c++-6

I am migrating a project from Visual Studio 6 to Visual Studio 9. The project is building and displaying correctly, but Visual Studio crashes if I try to open the resource view to edit the dialogs. The crashing was happening prior to me attemting to edit the text files directly, but the only change I made to the files is I removed `DS_MODALFRAME` from the dialogs.

Has anyone encoutered this issue before? How did you fix it?

I am not sure this will help much, but here is what debug spit out when I ran it on Visual Studio after the crash.

```
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_50934f2ebcb7eb57\msvcr90.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msimg32.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.7601.17825_none_72d273598668a06b\GdiPlus.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mscoree.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\profapi.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\clbcatq.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\msenv.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.atl_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_51cd0a7abbe4e19b\ATL90.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_41e6975e2bd6f2b2\comctl32.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sxs.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\1033\msenvui.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\1033\msenvmui.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcpackages\1033\vcpkgui.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcpackages\1033\VCProjectUI.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\urlmon.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wininet.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\iertutil.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\crypt32.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msasn1.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\VS SCC\VssProviderStub.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\VS SCC\1033\VssProviderStubui.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptsp.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rsaenh.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\RpcRtRemote.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\VS7Debug\coloader80.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools\VDT\1033\vdt80pui.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\1033\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.TestCaseManagementUI.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\VS SCC\1033\VssProviderui.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\1033\vsdebugui.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\vslog.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\1033\vslogui.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\custsat.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\msenvmnu.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\VS7Debug\msdbg2.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.6195_none_d09154e044272b9a\msvcr80.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\mscorlib\7150b9136fad5b79e88f6c7f9d3d2c39\mscorlib.ni.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE\9.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\microsoft.visualstudio.commonide.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorjit.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System\369f8bdca364e2b4936d18dea582912c\System.ni.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.Drawing\eead6629e384a5b69f9ae35284b7eeed\System.Drawing.ni.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.Windows.Forms\cb562e2e4f74ae607f1186f6ec50cec7\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\Microsoft.VisualStu#\e9a7669b967ee967fc5da55aff381040\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ni.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsCodecs.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\apphelp.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\EhStorShell.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\setupapi.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\propsys.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\GROOVEEX.DLL'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_50934f2ebcb7eb57\msvcp90.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE14\Cultures\OFFICE.ODF'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\1033\GrooveIntlResource.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntshrui.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\srvcli.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscapi.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\slc.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\VS SCC\VssProvider.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectAggregator.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcpackages\VCProject.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\secur32.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ws2_32.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nsi.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSEnv\msenvp.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcpackages\VCProjectEngine.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mpr.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msxml6.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dnsapi.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\IPHLPAPI.DLL'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winnsi.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mshtml.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\psapi.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msls31.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcpackages\VCProjectWCEPlatform.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntmarta.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Wldap32.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mlang.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcpackages\vcpkg.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\atlprov.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\vsdebug.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\1033\msvb7ui.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\encmgr.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\ecbuild.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wsock32.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Packages\Compsvcspkg.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Packages\1033\compsvcspkgui.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop\7.1.40304.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop\7.1.40304.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.8.0\8.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.8.0.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\Microsoft.Internal.#\1517ad5adc48f82780125ff81b17a475\Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.9.0.ni.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\Microsoft.VisualStudio.VSHelp80\8.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.VSHelp80.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\Microsoft.VisualStu#\1867791c5e29e2f2b3a432b40df41efc\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.9.0.ni.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.Design\31a8f96f8939ac18a867ee26cc37eda8\System.Design.ni.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.Xml\f687c43e9fdec031988b33ae722c4613\System.Xml.ni.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\System.Configuration\195a77fcc6206f8bb35d419ff2cf0d72\System.Configuration.ni.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rasapi32.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rasman.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rtutils.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mswsock.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WSHTCPIP.DLL'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wship6.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winhttp.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\webio.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\PeerDist.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\userenv.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\authz.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\credssp.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dhcpcsvc6.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dhcpcsvc.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\ieproxy.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\alink.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\mspdbcore.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcpackages\feacp.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\mspdb80.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\compluslm.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\vsmacros.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\1033\vsmacrosui.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\powrprof.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSEnv\VsLogP.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\Xml\Microsoft.XmlEditor.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\Microsoft.VisualStu#\865b6992e3b8f37c0d481ab2cd21b5af\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.9.0.ni.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Package.LanguageService.9.0\3.5.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Package.LanguageService.9.0.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop\7.1.40304.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.8.0\8.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\microsoft.visualstudio.textmanager.interop.8.0.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.XmlEditor\3.5.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.XmlEditor.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\EnvDTE\8.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\envdte.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Interop\8.0.1.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Interop.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Packages\htmled.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Packages\1033\Htmledui.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Packages\srcedit.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Packages\1033\Srceditui.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcpackages\bined.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.mfc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_4bf7e3e2bf9ada4c\mfc90.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\comdlg32.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.mfcloc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_49768ef57548175e\MFC90ENU.DLL', Binary was not built with debug information.
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcpackages\1033\reseditui.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcpackages\resedit.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.mfc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_4bf7e3e2bf9ada4c\mfc90u.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\Xml\1033\Microsoft.XmlEditorUI.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\ink\tiptsf.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleacc.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC#\VCSPackages\1033\csprojui.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\1033\Microsoft.VisualStudio.EnterpriseTools.ClassDesignerUI.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VB\Bin\1033\msvbprjUI.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Packages\1033\mswebprjui.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\1033\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SmartDevice.TestProjectUI.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Packages\1033\vdtflavui.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\SmartDevices\Projects\1033\SmartDeviceProjectUI.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\1033\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.TuipPackageUI.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSEnv\msenv90p.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin\RcDll.Dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcpackages\rcxdti.dll'
'devenv.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcpackages\1033\rcxdtiui.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1f28) has exited with code -1073740791 (0xc0000409).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1fe0) has exited with code -1073740791 (0xc0000409).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0xba4) has exited with code -1073740791 (0xc0000409).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0xf58) has exited with code -1073740791 (0xc0000409).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x43c) has exited with code -1073740791 (0xc0000409).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1c88) has exited with code -1073740791 (0xc0000409).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0xb70) has exited with code -1073740791 (0xc0000409).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x16d4) has exited with code -1073740791 (0xc0000409).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1f34) has exited with code -1073740791 (0xc0000409).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0xc30) has exited with code -1073740791 (0xc0000409).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0xef0) has exited with code -1073740791 (0xc0000409).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x15bc) has exited with code -1073740791 (0xc0000409).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x17c) has exited with code -1073740791 (0xc0000409).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x12ac) has exited with code -1073740791 (0xc0000409).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x172c) has exited with code -1073740791 (0xc0000409).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x890) has exited with code -1073740791 (0xc0000409).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1c24) has exited with code -1073740791 (0xc0000409).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0xd54) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1994) has exited with code -1073740791 (0xc0000409).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1624) has exited with code -1073740791 (0xc0000409).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1ef4) has exited with code -1073740791 (0xc0000409).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1de8) has exited with code -1073740791 (0xc0000409).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x14e0) has exited with code -1073740791 (0xc0000409).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0xdc0) has exited with code -1073740791 (0xc0000409).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1d80) has exited with code -1073740791 (0xc0000409).
The program '[4000] devenv.exe: Native' has exited with code -1073740791 (0xc0000409).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to remove the #include "newres.h" in the (project).rc file. I am not sure yet if there are any drawbacks from doing this.

```
#define  APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 2 resource.
//

#include  "afxres.h"
//#include "newres.h"

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#undef  APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
```